# Error not specified sqlcese40.dll

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have deployed my application to my customer. What happens is that I've tested my app in 4 different computers and works perfectly but not in my customer computer.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 in my code with SQL Compact and the customer has the .NET Framework 4.7 installed. I have also, just in case, installed the SQL Compact in his computer.

When I click in my app .exe a popup error is shown with the following text:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): Error not specified [ sqlcese40.dll ]
   in System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   in System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
   in System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
   in LongStoryShort.LoadAllByItems(String[] columns)
```

So the error occurs when connecting to database. Any clue what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I couldn't even uninstall the .NET Framework 4.7 in my customer PC because I was getting the error:

> The cryptographic operation failed due to a local security option
>   setting

After looking for answers about this error I end up in the microsoft website https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2715304/error-message-when-you-try-to-validate-a-copy-of-windows-the-cryptogra and did the steps on regedit like they say.

> This error occurs when the 'State' value of below mentioned registry
>   key is incorrectly set. This value corresponds to the Internet
>   Explorer security setting "Check for publisher’s certificate
>   Revocation" and "Check for signatures on downloaded programs"
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing You can find a key with the name
>   ‘State’. By default the values is set to – ‘23c00’ Resolution To
>   resolve this problem, change the registry key to a valid setting, e.g.
>
> State = 0x00023e00 - ‘Check for publisher’s certificate Revocation’ unchecked
>
> State = 0x00023c00 - ‘Check for publisher’s certificate Revocation’ Checked

After changing the regedit value my app started working instantly!